# set up my own vim attach where my counterpart can see my screen vice versa in ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, vim

I want my counterpart to see my screen to be about for him to view my codes while coding.

For example,

I have sample code for my partner to show, and I want it real time so we can collaborate together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using tmux for this. I haven't done pair programming with it, which is why I can't speak to how well it works, but here's someone who has:

http://remotepairprogramming.com/post/43644503063/remote-pair-programming-with-tmux-and-vim-the

There are tons of other resources about tmux, of course.

Comment: i tried to google about it and i found built in for linux which is screen. now my followup question: should i continue to install tmux or should i just used screen which is much better?

Comment: tmux is rich in features than screen

Comment: Both should work, though I have little experience with screen. You can easily install tmux through your linux distro's repository if you want to try them both and determine which suits your needs better.